# Jenkins GIT Authentication with Azure Devops Server using Personal Access Token

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops

**Summary:** Getting HTTP 401 while fetching sources from Azure Devops Server using personal access token with Jenkins

**Details:**
I have a Jenkins instance which is running in a Docker container, and I have a repository in Azure Devops Server.
When I execute following command in Jenkins instance, it is working without any problem:

```
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic <base64 of pat:token>" clone https://mytfsserver/my/project/_git/myrepo
```

But when I configure git crendetials in Jenkins and use git step it gets HTTP 401.

I used nginx as reverse proxy and tcpdump to capture network traffic:

[image: tcpdump]

It seems that, first two request is sent with out any authentication header (which is normal as I check with Azure Devops Services) but third and forth requests are sent with NTLM authentication header.

First Request:
[image: first request]
First Response:
[image: response of first request]

Third Request:
[image: third request]
Third Reponse:
[image: response of third request]

Forth Request:
[image: forth request]
Forth Response:
[image: response of forth request]

So, without touching anything at TFS and IIS side, is there any way to do something at Jenkins side to overcome this issue?

PS: Using JGit and JGit with Apache Http Client implementations didn't work.

PS: Using user password instead of access token works.